# How to comment in a closed group facebook api graph

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing on API Graph Facebook. I'm using `JavaScript SDK`. I want to comment in a group where I have published.

The problem is some groups are closed, although I am in these groups.

How can I comment in this groups?

For example, if I am in the explorer of Facebook developers I try to get a post mine, but when I execute the `GET` I obtain this error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '114576608727103_527470874104339' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "DVXM6hFnfeF"
  }
}
```

I have same problem when I try to use `POST` method. I can comment in a groups open normal.

*Note: I am in all groups that I want to comment.*

Thank you.

Comment: i believe it´s not possible. what would you post anyway? why not just use facebook.com?

Comment: Because I have a post in 8 different groups and I loss a lot of time commenting in every one. It's for this reason that I am doing a script, when I click in a button, Automatically publish a comment in everyone of my post.

Comment: What endpoint do you use to comment in open groups?

Comment: What do you mean with "endpoint" ? I have a static post in each group that I need. For example, I need to comment in a post mine I use next code fragment.

 FB.api('291689270953538_893820424073750/comments','POST',{"message":"."},  function(response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
     results =results + "<br>" + JSON.stringify(response) + "<br>";
       document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results;
but when I execute this code, It appear an error which is described up.

Comment: Broke down the beginning to be more clear. fixed some capitalization. Highlighted some specifics in code blocks. Put separate points on separate lines.

Comment: "Automatically publish a comment in everyone of my post" - what for? sounds like spam to me, what would the comment be? autoposting is not allowed anyway, you should not even do that in open groups.

Comment: This is not spam. It is a strategy, I am in a lot of groups for sell products, when I comment in any post, my publication first up on the list and people can see my publication again.

Comment: "why not use facebook.com?"  IDK, why does the Graph API exist? You can create posts, why not comments?  Regarding automatically publishing a comment in every post sounding like spam:  Maybe there's a valid reason to comment.  Suppose group members post cryptic things like 4 letter identifiers for airports.  It'd be nice if a group admin (or creator) could have a script that would automatically comment to decode those identifiers (give city and state) for the other group members who may not be familiar with that particular 4 letter ID.